# Sleeping an Application

Tags: .net, scheduled-tasks

I have a set of codes that has to be be run 3 times a day daily, i.e. 8am 12pm and 4pm. What is the best method to schedule these tasks in C# or VB. I don't want to use windows scheduler.

Comment: "I don't want to use windows scheduler". Why?

Comment: @Oded there is no specific reason as to why. just needed the output of the program to be recorded in logs along with few other values.

Comment: And why do you think you can't do that with the windows scheduler?

Comment: @You can write your application that do the tasks and finish when done, then setup windows task scheduler to run it the times you want it to. And you get everything you wanted with it with less hassle. And at the same time let your network administrators be able to handle the frequency it runs if that need to change without code changes.

Comment: @Oded a small problem is there. the task may sometimes takes long time to process. By that time task scheduler throws an error that its not responding

Comment: Not sure I've ever encountered that problem before, have over 20 tacks running every day, some insane cpu intensive and can take up to a hour. If you have problems with this, I would say make your service responsive by creating a background worker thread that do the work.

Answer (score 4):

The best way *is* the windows scheduler.

Runner up : Use a Windows-Service with a Timer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don`t want to use Scheduler.

You can write your own Windows Service, which can trigger yours "set of codes"

**How to: Write Services Programmatically**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76477d2t(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I agree the best way is window scheduler. But an [open source implementation of Cron](http://code.google.com/p/ncron/) could be an intyeresting alternative. I did not test it anyway

Answer (score 0):

In your case windows service with timers tick event is the best solution.
to create a window service with timer is explain here:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/cpp_managed/windowsservices/article.php/c6919/Using-Timers-in-a-Windows-Service.htm